# Is there any particular reason or case I wouldn't be able to add a new field to a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, serverless

I'm currently making my first steps as a backend developer.

It was built with Node.js, Serverless, MongoDB, in a microservices design pattern.

I'm having a problem with something that I thought was simple and that I've done multiple times before: adding a field to a Mongoose Schema.

Here's the original Schema :

```
const collectionName = "A";

const CollectionSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    AType: String,
    userId: String,
    origin: String,
    timestamp: Date,
    value: Number,
    context: String,
    sport: {
        matchId: String,
        teamId: String,
        actionId: String,
        matchTime: String,
        followedTeam: String,
    },
    pro: {
        eventId: String,
        subjectId: String,
    },
    comment: String,
    orgs: [String],
    sex: String,
    birthDate: String,
    test: {
        type: String,
        default: "TEST"
    }
});
```

Same one with the field I'm trying to add :

```
const collectionName = "A";

const CollectionSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    AType: String,
    userId: String,
    origin: String,
    timestamp: Date,
    value: Number,
    context: String,
    newElementId: String, **//<------- new field**
    sport: {
        matchId: String,
        teamId: String,
        actionId: String,
        matchTime: String,
        followedTeam: String,
    },
    pro: {
        eventId: String,
        subjectId: String,
    },
    comment: String,
    orgs: [String],
    sex: String,
    birthDate: String,
    test: {
        type: String,
        default: "TEST"
    }
});
```

After hitting the lambda, then goes :

```
    try {
        MyCollection = mongoose.model(collectionName);
    } catch (e) {
        MyCollection = mongoose.model(collectionName, CollectionSchema);
    }
    
export async function postMyAction(content: MyInterface): Promise<string> {
        console.log('Content => ', content); **// <---- new field appears**
        try {
            await db.connect();
            const value = await MyCollection.create(content);
    
            console.log('Returned value after creation => ', value); **// <---- new field does not appear**
            
            return value._id;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

**TROUBLESHOOTING:**

If you pay attention to the console logs,

-the new field was actually added to the schema since it appears in the content I'm sending to Mongo.

-Though, it does not show in the returned value afterward.

And although the object was created in mongoDB, the new field was not added.

All the microservices are built with the same pattern, and it never has been a problem before.

Any hint or suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this and make changes according to your requirements

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema =mongoose.Schema({
    _id  : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true},
    password        : { type: String, required: true },
    friends         :[new mongoose.Schema({
    user:{type:String}
},{strict:false})],
    profileImage: {type : String, default:"default.jpg"},
    userName    :{type :String, required : true},
    fullName    :{type: String, required : true},
    credits     : {type: Number, default:0},
    Tags   :{type : Object,default: null},
    backgroundImage : {type:String, default :"default.jpg"},
    isDeleted : {type : Boolean , default : false},
    deletedAt : {type: Date, default : null},
},{timestamps : true},{strict: false} );

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks for your answer. Just tried the solution you provided, but the issue remains the same. My POST action is recorded in MongoDB, but it does not take the new schema into consideration, the new field does not show.